How does pickle find modules when loading from a file?
I'm trying to understand how pickling works so that I can correctly design the organization of my repository. Essentially, I pickle objects of type A, whose instances contain objects of type B. A and B are defined in modules in separate packages:
project_dir
|
|-- package_a
  |
  |-- module_a  # class A is defined here
|
|-- package_b
  |
  |-- module_b # class B is defined here

I did an experiment that I expected to fail, given my knowledge about how pickling works, but it didn't throw an exception:
module_a.py:
class A:
    name = "A"

module_b.py:
class B:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = None

In one terminal window:
project_dir> python
>>> import pickle
>>> from package_a.module_a import A 
>>> from package_b.module_b import B 
>>> b_obj = B()   
>>> b_obj.a = A() 
>>> b_obj.a.name  
'A'
>>> with open("b.pickle", "wb") as f:
...     pickle.dump(b_obj, f)
...
>>> exit()

In a new terminal window:
project_dir> python
>>> import pickle
>>> from package_b.module_b import B
>>> with open("b.pickle", "rb") as f:
...     b_obj = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> b_obj.a.name 
'A'

How is pickle able to construct an A object when I haven't imported module_a anywhere?
EDIT: When I modify A to have a getter for the class name attribute:
class A:
    name = "A"

    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls):
        return cls.name

The following experiment still works:
project_dir> python
>>> import pickle
>>> from package_a.module_a import A
>>> from package_b.module_b import B
>>> b_obj = B()
>>> b_obj.a = A()
>>> b_obj.a.get_name()
'A'
>>> b_obj.a.__class__
<class 'package_a.module_a.A'>
>>> with open("b.pickle", "wb") as f:
...     pickle.dump(b_obj, f)
... 
>>> exit()

>>> import pickle
>>> from package_b.module_b import B
>>> with open("b.pickle", "rb") as f:
...     b_obj = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> b_obj.a.get_name()
'A'
>>> b_obj.a.__class__
<class 'package_a.module_a.A'>

This seems contrary to the pickle docs, which state that

...when class instances are pickled, their class’s code and data are not pickled along with them. Only the instance data are pickled.

What exactly is going on under the hood here?

Pickling an instance will store the module name, the class name, and the instance attributes.  Unpickling imports that module, looks up the class name within it. creates a blank instance, and stores the attributes in it.  (I'm ignoring some possible variations on the process, this is just the basic overview.)

I updated my question to better clarify my confusion.

It's not storing the class code, just the information about the module that defines the code. So when it loads the file, it can load the relevant module.

Just an aspect I'd like to mention: I stopped using pickle and try rather to serialize the class attributes using json or yaml for the sake of transparency. The reason is that pickle logically fails to load the data once you change the class attributes. Hence, if you develop your software further, the old pickle files will at some point fail to load.
Well, it's still good for very temporary storage (like in multi-processing), and for performance reasons in specific cases.

@Barmar so then if I pickle a custom class object that contains instances of other nested objects, it will find and load all modules necessary to reconstruct those objects? This is the root of my question, so if you could provide me with some documentation that answers this, I would appreciate it.

@Dr.V That's a good point. In my case, the pickled objects are just for convenient loading of data, but the pipeline contains the code needed to rebuild them in the case of any class changes. But your suggestion is certainly a more robust solution if I wanted to store serialized objects.

I don't see anything in the documentation that goes into this detail. But how else can it possibly work?

Well from everything I've read about pickling, I expected it not to work. I thought that it would only work if I had imported module_a before unpickling the object.
